# Scanner.next() and Scanner.nextLine()

Tags: java

I have the following code:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
String[] data = new String[5];

System.out.println("Please, enter the name of the customer ordering:");
data[0] = in.next();
System.out.print("Please, enter the assembly details: ");
data[1] = in.nextLine();
System.out.print("Please, enter the assembly id:");
data[2] = in.next();
System.out.println("Please, enter the date the assembly was ordered (MM-DD-YYYY):");
data[3] = in.next();
```

I am trying to get nextLine() to read more than a single word, but at the moment of testing it, it simply jumps to the next Scanning for data[2]. I need help. I have no idea what to do.

Comment: Sample Input? nextLine reads up to and including the first end of line char.

Comment: please when you post this kind of questions be kind enough to post the relevant `inputs` and `outputs`. :)

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
    Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
    String[] data = new String[5];

    System.out.println("Please, enter the name of the customer ordering:");
    data[0] = in.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Please, enter the assembly details: ");
    data[1] = in.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Please, enter the assembly id:");
    data[2] = in.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Please, enter the date the assembly was ordered (MM-DD-YYYY):");
    data[3] = in.nextLine();
    in.close();
```

You should be using `nextLine()` and not `next()` to read each line from console

Answer (score 0):

next() -- Finds and returns the next complete token from this scanner
nextLine() --Advances this scanner past the current line and returns the input that was skipped.

From the java API documentation.

Comment: Right. I read it, but it only confused me more, that is why I came here to ask.

Comment: @Yokhen : post sample inputs for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `next()` and `nextLine()` together if you don't know what you're doing, it easily results in errors. `next()` reads the next input token, `nextLine()` all tokens until next line. So if you have inputs like this:

> John\nSquirrels

(\n is newline character)

The first `next()` returns "John" and leaves us

> \nSquirrels

After which a `nextLine()` is facing no tokens before the end of the line, so you get an empty String instead of "Squirrels".